# HTTP response code for refund already done

Tags: rest, http

I am writing rest api which takes transaction id as a input and processes refund for the specified transaction. So there can be case where I received multiple refund requests for the same transaction. But refund can be processed only once. In the case what should be the response code if refund is already done and I received duplicate request for refund of same transaction ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`403`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) to indicate that the operation is forbidden or [`409`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) to indicate a conflict in the state of the resource:

> [**6.5.3.  403 Forbidden**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3)
>
> The `403` (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that wishes to make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that reason in the response payload (if any).
>
> If authentication credentials were provided in the request, the server considers them insufficient to grant access. [...] However, a request might be forbidden for reasons unrelated to the credentials. [...]

> [**6.5.8.  409 Conflict**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8)
>
> The `409` (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not
> be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target
> resource.  This code is used in situations where the user might be
> able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.  The server
> SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user
> to recognize the source of the conflict. [...]

It's essential to return a good description of the error in the response paylod. You could use the [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) as reference.

Comment: 409 makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `423` Locked. Unlike `422` Unprocessable Entity, which CAN be used to indicate that the request can't be processed due its state, `423` Locked CAN be used to indicate that the request can't be processed due the resource state.

The problem with `403` is that it's related to authorization, telling the requesting user doesn't have enough permission, meaning it could be done with elevated permission.

The problem with `409` is that it indicates the conflict could be solved by the user and retried again later.

But also the problem with `423` is that it could be unlocked. At least it gets closer by telling "the request can't be processed due the source state", which fits.